# matplotlib imshow - use matrix as y axis values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Here is a very simplified version of what I'd like to do:

```
In [44]: data = np.array([[0]*3,[1]*3,[2]*3])

In [45]: data
Out[45]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2]])

In [46]: xaxis = np.array([0,1,2])

In [47]: yaxis = np.array([[0,0.1,0.4],[1.1,1.6,1.9],[2.3,2.6,4]])

In [48]: yaxis
Out[48]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0.1,  0.4],
       [ 1.1,  1.6,  1.9],
       [ 2.3,  2.6,  4. ]])
```

I would like to make an `imshow()` plot using the yaxis values from the grid. (Each data value in "data" is an intensity value associated with its equivalent position in the yaxis grid)

Answer (score 0):

I think the `y-axis` has to be extended, in this case to 41 pixels. Then a new array `data2` of dimension (3, 41) is created. This is filled with the values given in `data` at the positions for `xaxis` and `yaxis` transformed to the new y-axis. `data2` can be plotted by `imshow`. It's not a really simple solution.

```
data = np.array([[0]*3,[1]*3,[2]*3])

xaxis = np.array([0,1,2])

yaxis = np.array([[0,0.1,0.4],[1.1,1.6,1.9],[2.3,2.6,4]])

# expand the y-axis to 4/0.1 = 40 in this case
ydim = int(np.max(yaxis)/np.min(yaxis[where(yaxis!=0.)])) + 1

# create new data array of size (len(xaxis), ydim)
data2 = np.zeros((len(xaxis), ydim))

# fill the new data array according to the values given in data at the positions specified in xaxis and yaxis
for i in xaxis:
    for nr, j in enumerate(yaxis[i]):
        data2[i,int(j*10)] = data[i, nr]
# use interpolation='nearest' to clarify the behaviour and extent x-axis to 40
imshow(data2, extent = (0, ydim-1, ydim-1, 0), interpolation='nearest')
show()
```

[image: created picture]